# How to draw inward arrows between two paths?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw inward arrows between two paths, like in the picture below?

[image]

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you made an attempt and let us know what you are stuck on. Perhaps you can provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem by drawing the circle and the other shape.  I am assuming that you can draw those elements since your question is about the arrows. And perhaps some info as to how you want to specify where the arrows are to originate and terminate at.

Comment: Can you at least give the code for the wiggly curve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an option using [`hobby`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hobby) for the "wiggly" curve, the `intersections` library to determine appropriate points over the curves, and the `decorations.markings` library to place the arrows in the middle of the segments between the curves; the segments correspond to portions of lines steaming from the center of the circle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby,intersections,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
decoration={
  markings,
  mark= at position 0.5 with {\arrow{latex}}
  },
  line width=1pt
]
\draw[name path=circle] 
  (0,0) circle [radius=3cm];
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\draw[name path=curve,orange!70!black]
  (4,1) to[closed, curve through={
    (3,4) .. (2,4) .. (0,5) .. (-4,0) .. (1,-5) .. (0,-3) .. (2,-5) .. (4,-3) .. (2,0)}]  cycle;
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\foreach \Angulo in {0,10,...,360}
{
  \path[overlay,name path=line-\Angulo] (0,0) -- (\Angulo:10cm);
  \path[overlay,name intersections={of=circle and line-\Angulo,name=i}] 
    (0,0) -- (\Angulo:10cm);
  \path[overlay,name intersections={of=curve and line-\Angulo,name=j}] 
    (0,0) -- (\Angulo:10cm);
  \draw[blue!70!black,postaction=decorate] (j-1) -- (i-1);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This should give you some idea.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,10}{
     \draw (4,0) arc(0:360:4cm) node[coordinate,pos=0.\x] (a-\x) {};
     \draw[thick, red]
      (3,2) arc(0:360:4cm) node[coordinate,pos=0.\x] (b-\x) {};
     \draw[decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with
        {\arrow{latex}}},
     postaction={decorate}] (b-\x) -- (a-\x);
     }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a more curvy line with `hobby`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,10}{
     \draw (4,0) arc(0:360:4cm) node[coordinate,pos=0.\x] (a-\x) {};
     \draw[thick, red,decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.\x with
        {\node[fill,circle,inner sep=2pt,pos=0.\x] (b-\x) {};}},
     postaction={decorate}]
      (4,1) to[closed, curve through={(3,4) .. (1,3) ..
        (-2,5)..(-5,0)..(-3,-5)..(0,-3)..(2,-5)..(3,-3)}]  cycle;
     \draw[decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with
         {\arrow{latex}}},
         postaction={decorate}] (a-\x) -- (b-\x);
     }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don"t think this is quite what the OP wants: from their image, it looks like the arrows should always be pointing at the centre of the black circle.

Comment: @Jake Oh. I got your point now. But as I said, this is just for providing some idea, not to draw the image for the OP. :-)